# How to use network interfaces as a bridge for another PC?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a server (let's call it **PC1**) which I cannot connect to the internet "normally" for various reasons. I have another PC (**PC2**) with wireless a wireless connection and an available network port. I have connected PC1 directly to PC2. PC1s gateway is PC2s eth0. The gateway of PC2s eth0 is PC2s wlan0 whose gateway is my router. PC1 can ping PC2s eth0 and wlan0, who can conversely ping the router. PC1 is unable to do this and cannot connect to the internet.

#### To illustrate:

```
PC1 ---> PC2(eth0) ---> PC2(wlan0) ---> Router`
```

***tl;dr***

I am trying to connect a Linux PC, through another Linux PCs wireless connection, to the internet

**NOTE:** I have tried a different configuration whereby the default gateway of PC2s eth0 was the router and achieved the same results.

**NOTE-2:** I have a really cheap router to whom I am unable to connect wirelessly with a static address.

#### PC1 output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.105      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

#### PC2 output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

I have forwarding enabled. PC1s IP is 10.0.1.104, PC2(eth0) is 10.0.1.105, PC2(wlan0) is 10.0.0.103 and the router is 10.0.0.138.

How can I connect PC1 to the internet?

Comment: it'd possibly be clearer to at least some, if you stated the IPs of PC1 and PC2

Comment: also bear in mind that IIRC in linux, something along the lines of  ip forwarding required for routing is turned off by default  so you have to turn it on.  Something like this https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux    otherwise even if it receives a packet from another computer, it won't forward that packet on. Even if your routing table is correct.

Comment: i guess pc2's IP is 10.0.1.105 (pc1's gateway) ? And PC1 is something on 10/8 and changes, and  10.0.0.138 is your router's local/private ip.

Comment: also i'm no expert, but I don't think bridging is the same as using one as an intermediate router to share a commection. Bridging sounds like something done at the MAC address level, which is different from the IP level.

Comment: He should probably look into IP forwarding or so. Even if it can be done with bridging, one will need two wired NICs to do that, since AFAIK, the bridge "driver" in Linux kernel does not support a wireless NIC to be a bridge port in non-AP mode.